# Using ADODB to write to Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, adodb

I hope someone can give me some direction using the ADODB methods to accomplish my goal.

Brief explanation:

*Currently* I have code in Outlook VBA that searches an email. If the email passes criteria the Outlook macro **opens** an Excel workbook, loops through column A to see if an ID number exists. If it does it updates other columns (1 or more columns), if not it creates a new row and writes data into Columns A-C for that row. Then saves and closes the workbook.

*I want* to speed up the process and the limiting factor is opening the excel workbook (located on a share drive). I have used a simple ADODB macro to read data in another workbook and have seen the speed increases possible. I want to implement that here.

I have been able to establish connection to the workbook from Outlook and place data into a recordset. BUT I don't know how to "loop" through the first column to see if the ID exists yet or not, and further more how to write data into the columns in the workbook (UPDATE SQL command?).

ExcelConnection Code:

```
Public Sub ExcelConnect(msg As Outlook.MailItem, LType As String)

    Dim lngrow As Long
    Dim SourceFile As Variant   'used
    Dim SourceSheet As String   'used
    Dim SourceRange As String   'used

    SourceFile = "T:\Capstone Proj\TimeStampsOnlyTest.xlsx"
    SourceSheet = "Timestamps"
    SourceRange = "A2:F500"



    Dim rsCon As Object     'used
    Dim rsData As Object    'used
    Dim szConnect As String ' used
    Dim szSQL As String     ' used
    Dim lCount As Long

    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"";"
        Else
            szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"";"
        End If

        szSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SourceSheet$ & "$" & SourceRange$ & "];"

        Set rsCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        Set rsData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

        rsCon.Open szConnect
        rsData.Open szSQL, rsCon, 0, 1, 1

    '***Need Help implementing a way to find exisiting ID numbers, or if Exisiting = 0 then INSERT new row into worksheet***'

    Select Case LType '// Choose which columns based on Type
    Case "MDIQE"
    '        If columnvalue = 0 Then
    '        Update column value
    Case "MDIQ"
    '        If columnvalue = 0 Then
    '        Update column value
    '        
    '........
    '
    Case "MDIF"
    '        If columnvalue = 0 Then
    '        Update column value
    '        
    End Select

'Error handing & success messagebox

End sub
```

Thank you for the help,
Wagner

Answer (score 0):

In your `SELECT` statement, include a `WHERE` clause to search for the ID in column A, something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) c
  FROM [sourceSheet$sourceRange]
 WHERE <ColumnAName> = <ID>
```

<sup>*note, this is pseudocode, you'll have to properly assemble the statement just like you did when you assigned a string to `szSQL`*</sup>

Then check your result set for the value of `c`, something like this:

```
If rsData.Fields("c").value = 0 Then
  'ID was NOT found, execute SQL INSERT here
Else
  'ID was found, execute SQL UPDATE here
End If
```

i.e., treat your Excel worksheet like a database.

Of course, it would be better if you could use Access as a database (or SQL Server, or Oracle, or ...) since, well, that's what they're designed to do. But I understand that sometimes you've just got to roll with what you've got.